# My e.graphics.drawimage(mybitmap,200,200) is drawing my bitmap at 200,222. Why?

Tags: c#, graphics, drawimage

I initialize my bitmap here

```
Bitmap x = new Bitmap("andgateopen.bmp");
```

and it's size is 68x44. When I try to draw it here:

```
private void toolbox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(x, 200, 200);
}
```

It shows up at 200,222 on my screen. Why is this happening? If I draw the bitmap using `e.Graphics.DrawImage(x, 200, 178)` then it shows up correctly. Where are these 22 units?

Solved (Sort of) - It's the title bar. Since it's always a consistent 23 units, I can account for it consistently. Thanks to TaW for help.

Comment: 22 is half of the pictures height, maybe some issues with the image stride? Does that happen for arbitrary images?

Comment: Or: 22 pixels sounds like a TitleBar's Height. How do you measure the result?

Comment: Yeah it happens for all images. I think it has to do with the bar at the top that has minimize and maximize in it. It seems that that is 23 units deep and my program things 0,0 is at the VERY top left of my screen instead of the past the thing. Is there a way to get my mouse coordinates WITHIN my program. Rather, relative to the screen image (with 0,0 at the start of the window and not my screen?

Comment: Use:  `Text =  "" + toolbox.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition); ` to display the mouse location relative to the `toolbox` control..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Graphics instance doesn't have an identity Transform.

```
e.Graphics.Transform = new Matrix();
```

It might also depend on which units you are drawing in. Device, World or Point.

Comment: Visual studio 2012 doesn't seem to know what a matrix is. Also I don't know what "units" I'm drawing in. I'm getting my coords from Cursor.Position. to compare my bitmap to the rest of the code.

Comment: "Visual studio 2012 doesn't seem to know what a matrix is". No, it would know, if you include the right stuff.

Comment: As the code shows he is using the default Graphics object without any changes.